# How to substitute whitesapaces and tabs in a string with _ in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$string = I am a boy
```

How to substitute whitespaces between words with underscore ?

Comment: Your code is not valid.

Comment: Did you even try anything before asking this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a regular expression and the substitution operator to do that.

```
my $string = 'I am a boy';
$string =~ s/\s/_/g;
```

You can learn more about regex in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). A nice tool to play around with is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).

---

Also, your code will not compile. You need to quote your string, and you need to put a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Perl has bare words and does not require a semicolon at the end of blocks, so that may not be true.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Wrong. Try compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'I am a boy';
$string =~ s/ /_/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string =~ tr( \t)(_);  # Double underscore not necessary as per Dave's comment
```

Comment: You don't need the double underscore. From the docs - "if the REPLACEMENTLIST is shorter than the SEARCHLIST, the final character is replicated till it is long enough".

Answer (score 0):

**This is just to show another option in perl.**  I think `Miguel Prz` and `imbabque` showed more smarter ways, personally i follow the way `imbabque` showed.

```
my $str = "This is a test string";
$str =~ s/\p{Space}/_/g;
print $str."\n";
```

**and the output is**

```
This_is_a_test_string
```